# jQuery .animate conflicting with CSS3 animation applied to the same element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slideshow

I'm using the following javascript to navigate through a CSS3 slideshow of 4 videos. The slideshow is set up to play infinitely with CSS3 keyframes. The videos are all set to auto play.

As it stands the .animate isn't working as when you click next/previous it just jumps straight to that slide. I've tried taking the keyframe animation off and the .animate works fine I can navigate through perfectly, put it back and it breaks.

This is the rough setup... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D5Qcw/9/)

Any ideas how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

JS

```
//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $('#carousel .video-list li').outerWidth(); 
var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#previous').click(function() {
//get the right position            
var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel .video-list').css('left')) + item_width;
//slide the item            
$('#carousel .video-list').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200,function(){    

$(".video-list, #timeline, .description-list").css({"animation-play-state": "paused", "-    
webkit-animation-play-state": "paused"});    

    //move the last item and put it as first item                
    $('#carousel .video-list li:first').before($('#carousel .video-list li:last'));           
    //set the default item to correct position
    $('#carousel .video-list').css({'left' : left_value});

});
//cancel the link behavior            
return false;

});

//if user clicked on next button
$('#next').click(function() {

//get the right position
var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel .video-list').css('left')) - item_width;

//slide the item
$('#carousel .video-list').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200, function () {

    $(".video-list, #timeline, .description-list").css({"animation-play-state": "paused", 
"-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused"});

    //move the first item and put it as last item
    $('#carousel .video-list li:last').after($('#carousel .video-list li:first'));                     

    //set the default item to correct position
    $('#carousel .video-list').css({'left' : left_value});

});

//cancel the link behavior
return false;

});
```

Comment: You can't use both. Lets say you animate from 0 to 300px using jQuery. It will go 0,1,2,3... until it reaches 300. Now if you add css transitions on top of that, it will try to do a css transition in between EACH number. You can see why that would mess things up.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, ok I thought that might have been the case. Is there a way round it that you might suggest?

Comment: Use one or the other. You might also check out this nice plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/  Basically, it lets you use CSS animations like you would normally use jQuery ones.

Comment: I don't suppose you could help me with this I'm having trouble getting the jquery.transit plugin you suggested to work properly. It's doing what I want but only firing once and seems a bit glitchy so I've clearly gone wrong somewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/9/

Comment: When you slide, are you telling it "move left 1000 pixels", or are you saying "move left 1000 pixels from where I am now"? The first one might be causing the problem where it only works once.